# What is the syntax in pynput for the Num Lock Key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

In my program I use pynput to control my mouse and keyboard. Everything else working as intended but I cannot find the syntax to reference using the Num Lock key on my keyboard

```
keyboard.press(Key.nmlk)
```

This is my current guess at what the syntax might be (nmlk). Can anyone please guide me to finding the right word or work around to be able to press the number lock key?

Thank you

Comment: The _syntax_ is right, but why are you guessing the value? https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/blob/fbf5268ad46efd622e15465f1b44c6a9047bf81f/lib/pynput/keyboard/_base.py#L306:L307

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation. Next time, please try e.g. putting `pynput num lock` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pynput+num+lock); when I try this, I get the linked duplicate as the second result, and the relevant documentation as the third; and if I scroll a little further I can even find a [fully worked tutorial example](https://gist.github.com/alexandrecvieira/2a3a9ab6402ae6dac974673b6a4dae23).

Answer (score 1):

According to [the official docs](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.Key.num_lock), they NumLock key is called `num_lock`.